# Why is the imported module not available for use?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

In AndroidStudio I added a new module to put test vectors that are needed in multiple other modules' tests. I used the "Android Library" template to bootstrap that module.

I added the dependency to the new module to my Android app's instrumentation test and to a library's unit test respectively:

```
app/build.gradle:
dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation project(':testhelper')
}
someJavaLibrary/build.gradle:
dependencies {
    testImplementation project(':testhelper')
}
```

Syncing gradle worked fine but I can use a class from that module only in the app's test, not in the library's test.

Answer (score 0):

The "Android Library" template can't be used in a non-Android module. Remove all things Android from its build.gradle and it should work.